# Share objects in a linked list between many classes(java)

Tags: java, class, object, linked-list, share

i´m working on a project that involves many classes and a lot of objects....i have a class(main) that save objects into a linked list, later other classes(main too) will show the attributes of any object saved in the linked list acording the user needs. i want to know how do i share the objects saved in the first main class to other classes...then modify the list in other class and update the list as well..

This is the code when i add objects to the linked list...

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
int i;
i=(combo.getSelectionIndex());
problema.setUsuario(combo.getItem(i));
problema.setLugar(text.getText());
problema.setCodigoequipo(text_3.getText());
lista.add(problema);//the adding
shell.close();
```

later... when i´m consulting the objects in other class i need to show some attributes of them.
i'll appreciate your answers :)

Comment: i can´t get attributes from a object saved in a linked list(in other classes), thats my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linked list has references to all the objects it contains. In order to share the objects, you only need to pass a reference to the linked list.

Comment: seems like easy..but i don´t know what a reference in java means

Comment: Well then you don't know Java. Try looking for a tutorial online.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get familiar with java.util.Collection and related classes...and doing google searches on full java class names, they will tell you plenty... add on *tutorial* if necessary....